# que dices tiempo vs qué dices tiempo: How will the accent mark change the meaning?

Tags: significado

In Spanish, punctuation is soooo important, especially to new language learners.

I encounter so many song lyrics that inconsistently include punctuation. Therefore, I'm always unsure if the absence of an accent mark is intentional or not.

See the bolded text in the following verse from the song *Eres para mí* by Juleta Venegas:

> Temes sentir más de la cuenta
>
> El corazón es un músculo si no late revienta
>
> Extraño, mirarte de lejos
>
> De hacernos los tontos parecemos tan viejos
>
> **Tiempo, que dices tiempo**
>
> Mírame en la piel
>
> No ves acaso lo que siento
>
> Tú eres para mí yo soy para ti
>
> El viento me lo dijo con un soplo suavecillo

I'm not confident that the Internet has provided the proper lyrics. That is, should it be "Tiempo, **que** dices tiempo," or should it be "Tiempo, qu**é** dices tiempo."

One little accent mark can change the entire meaning:

> Tiempo, **que** dices tiempo = *Time, you say time*
>
> Tiempo, qu**é** dices tiempo = *Time, what about time*

Is there anyone that is familiar enough with this song to know what is the proper translation of this one line within the context of the song?

Comment: Que is sometimes used to refer a pronoun. So I think it should be the first one. But whatever it is, this song is kind of difficult, I mean that it is more like a poem so if you are a beginner I wouldn'r recoment you this, since I'm spanish and even though I have some dificulties to undertand the whole meaning of that.

Comment: After adding a comma (*Tiempo, qué dices, tiempo*), the second option actually translates to *Time, what do you say, time*. An alternative and somewhat informal interpretation without the comma could be *time, what do you mean time*, as in *A: necesitamos darnos un tiempo. B: ¿Qué dices tiempo? Lo que necesitamos es no vernos más*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The transcription you found is incorrect. The actual lyrics are:

> ¿Tiempo? ¿Quieres más tiempo?
>
> Mírame la piel, ¿no ves acaso lo que siento?
>
> Tú eres para mí, yo soy para ti

You can listen to that part [here](https://youtu.be/pj2ntDiXJCk?t=119) (1:59). It can be translated as:

> Time? You are asking for more time?
>
> Look at my skin, can't you see how I feel?
>
> You are for me, I am for you

She is trying to say to her love interest that he shouldn't ask for more time to admit their feelings, they are obviously made for each other.

Comment: Arrrgh! I need to find an official source for lyrics!!!!! At least I have you fine folks at StackExchange to help. If not for you, I wouldn't know that "no ves acaso lo que siento" was presented as a question!!!

Comment: Also, what is the significance of placing 'acaso' in "¿no ves acaso lo que siento?"? Thanks.

Comment: @RockAnthonyJohnson in this case is a way to add emphasis, like: *Really, can't you see it? It's obvious*

Comment: @RockAnthonyJohnson It's emphatic as said. Normally it uses a simple form to make the question: *don't you see what I feel?*

Comment: One more thing: "Mírame en la piel" or "Mírame la piel", are these idioms that have special meaning beyond the literal translation, "Look at my skin"?